# How to prevent menu to be closed each time when selecting checkbutton

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

The following is my code example.
It is very annoying to reopen menu every time when it needs to select several options. Since every time checkbox selected,  the menu closed automatically. 
How can I prevent it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish


frame .top
pack .top -expand yes -fill both 
wm title . TEST

menubutton .top.fillmet -text "select fill metals" -menu .top.fillmet.mtls  

set m .top.fillmet.mtls
menu $m

$m add checkbutton -label "fill m2" -variable fillm2 -onvalue "fillm2" -offvalue ""

$m add checkbutton -label  "fill m3"  -variable fillm3  -onvalue "fillm3"  -offvalue ""
$m add checkbutton -label  "fill m4"  -variable fillm4  -onvalue "fillm4"  -offvalue ""
$m add checkbutton -label  "fill m5"  -variable fillm5  -onvalue "fillm5"  -offvalue ""
$m add checkbutton -label  "fill m6"  -variable fillm6  -onvalue "fillm6"  -offvalue ""
$m add checkbutton -label  "fill m7"  -variable fillm7  -onvalue "fillm7"  -offvalue ""
$m add checkbutton -label  "fill m8"  -variable fillm8  -onvalue "fillm8"  -offvalue ""
$m add checkbutton -label  "fill m9"  -variable fillm9  -onvalue "fillm9"  -offvalue ""
$m add checkbutton -label  "fill m10" -variable fillm10 -onvalue "fillm10" -offvalue ""
$m add checkbutton -label  "fill m11" -variable fillm11 -onvalue "fillm11" -offvalue ""
$m add checkbutton -label  "fill m12" -variable fillm12 -onvalue "fillm12" -offvalue ""


pack .top.fillmet
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a different method would work better for this particular user interface?

This will display a new toplevel window with a list of options that
can be selected.  The global `fillm` array will be populated with the
results.

```
proc doOptions { } {
  global fillm

  set w .optfillmet
  toplevel $w
  for {set i 2} {$i < 13} {incr i} {
     checkbutton $w.cb$i -text "fill m$i" -variable fillm($i) \
          -onvalue fillm$i -offvalue ""
     pack $w.cb$i -in $w -side top -anchor w
  }
  button $w.b -text close -command [list destroy $w]
  pack $w.b -in $w -side top -anchor e
}

frame .top
pack .top -expand yes -fill both 
wm title . TEST

# .top.fillmet.mtls ; # redundant line
menu .top.fillmet 
.top.fillmet add command -label "select fill metals" -command doOptions
. configure -menu .top.fillmet
```

Comment: I think that your proposal is really good.
However I can use the same technique just by clicking on dotted line in my example. So menu will turn into independent window and will not closed automatically after I select checkbox. Might be you know more elegant solution.